# jenkins skip build if no changes

Tags: jenkins

I have pipeline script like below

My question is when i am build this job. If some thing change in scm in Stage "B". I need to build this one only other two stages need to skip. How can skip  this stage A & C.

```
stage 'a'
node ('master'){

  git branch: "${git_branch}", credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", url: 'http://'


  sh "${tool 'mvn'}/bin/mvn -f obs-infra/pom.xml  clean install cobertura:cobertura -U -Dmaven.test.skip=false -Dcobertura.report.format=xml -s " 



stage 'B'

  git branch: "${git_branch}", credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", url: 'https:commons.git'

  sh "${tool 'mvn'}/bin/mvn -f obs-commons/pom.xml  clean install -DskipTests=true -s" 


stage 'c'


  git branch: "${git_branch}", credentialsId: "${credentialsId}", url: ''http://kms.git"

  sh "${tool 'mvn'}/bin/mvn -f obs-kms/pom.xml  clean install  -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true  " 
}
```

Comment: Not clear the question. Could you please reformulate?

Comment: We have 3 stages in my pipeline like A B & C. When I am trigger my pipeline. First check scm if something changes in stage "A" Git repository need to build that job only.  if Nothing changes in repository. I don't need Build that Stage "A" i need to skip that stage "A" and go and Check Stage B. Same as stage " C".